# Can implicit class also be Dynamic?

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

I tried to add dynamic functionality to a class implicitly by doing the following:

```
case class C(map: Map[String, String])

implicit class Enhancer(c: C) extends Dynamic {
    def selectDynamic(str: String) = c.map.getOrElse(str, "")
}

val c = C(Map("a" -> "A"))
```

And this will not compile

```
val up = c.a
```

But an explicit call will:

```
val up = Enhancer(c).a
```

Why is this?

Comment: but you can access to the "selectDynamic" method from a C instance. Where is the a property defined? in Dynamic?

Comment: Implicit conversion (already too automagic in its own most of cases) + dynamic ... Would be a formula for unmaintainable code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule in [the specification](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/06-expressions.html#value-conversions) is

> Selection on Dynamic
>
> If none of the previous conversions applies, and `e`
> is a prefix of a selection `e.x`, and `e`'s type conforms to class `scala.Dynamic`, then the selection is rewritten according to the rules for dynamic member selection.

[Conformance](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/03-types.html#conformance) doesn't include "can be implicitly converted"; so no, you can't add `Dynamic` implicitly. You could propose it for some future version of Scala, but I would be surprised if it's accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this will compile...

```
val up = Enhancer(c).a  //up: String = A
```

...but then, so will this...

```
val up = Enhancer(c).wxyz  //up: String = ""
```

If class `C` doesn't have a member `a`, and class `Enhancer` doesn't have a member `a`, the compiler isn't going to check if `a` is supported dynamically because *everything* is supported dynamically.

If I were designing a language/compiler, and it came to a choice between allowing `a.anything` (because `Enhancer` is `Dynamic`), or allowing only natively supported members (ignoring dynamics), I think I'd go with the latter.

Comment: I think that's the point; they want both `c.a` and `c.wxyz` to compile.